How bad is the particulate matter problem at the "Sziget Festival" really? Is it true that everyone wears masks?
I would very much like to go to the Sziget Festival because I have read and heard a lot of positive things.

The Sziget Festival (Hungarian: Sziget Fesztivál, pronounced [ˈsiɡɛt
ˈfɛstivaːl]; "Sziget" for "Island") is one of the largest music and
cultural festivals in Europe. It is held every August in northern
Budapest, Hungary, on Óbudai-sziget ("Old Buda Island"), a leafy
108-hectare (266-acre) island on the Danube. More than 1,000
performances take place each year.

However, in TripAdvisor reviews you read about a big particulate matter problem. They write that everyone was coughing after the festival and everyone was wearing a mask. Is this really true, can anyone provide more background information?

From which year(s) were those reviews? Masks and coughing do remind me of covid and that is a changing scene.

Searching the reviews for "dust" looks like it was mentioned 2015, 2017, 2018, 2019 and a lot in 2022

2018 video here https://www.newsflare.com/video/235284/dust-storm-at-sziget-music-festival

And here is another complain of excessive dust, from a couple of years ago
